# Is there a way for C# to communicate with a Java server via JMX using MBeans?

Tags: c#, java, jmx

I have a server written to Java to service HTTP requests for various clients.  I also have some MBeans on this server exposed over JMX from which a monitoring tool can keep an eye on some the servers resources and assist in maintenance.

All code that system/integration tests HTTP endpoints is done is C#.  Because of this, I was hoping to try to use C# to also test my MBeans over JMX.  Does a library to do such a thing already exist, or would I have to go about implementing the protocol myself?  What other options (with C#) might I have?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a JMX Bridge like [Jolokia](http://www.jolokia.org) which exposes MBeans via HTTP and JSON to the outside world. Several client libraries are available (Java, Perl, Javascript), unfortunately not for C# yet. However, since the protocol is well [documented](http://www.jolokia.org/reference/html/protocol.html), it should not be that hard to access the Jolokia agents from C# as well. The protocol supports GET requests, so using it mostly only implies to create a proper HTTP Url, send the HTTP request and parse the HTTP-Response as JSON. There is also a [sample](http://www.jolokia.org/features/polyglot.html) how to do this in a bash script.

Comment: <spooky-noise>woooooo, I'm from the fuuutuuuure, woooo<spooky-noise>. There is a .NET client. https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dapplo.Jolokia/

Answer (score 2):

I can attest to the usability of Jolokia. Excellent product.
Two additional options:

- [JMX WebService Connector](http://ws-jmx-connector.java.net/): Install the WS JMXConnectorServer in the target JVM and you can use standard WebService calls to interact with the JMX server.
- [IKVM](http://www.ikvm.net/): This is a compiler that converts Java byte code to .NET byte code. The standard JMX remoting works fine from a C# client.